# Is it possible to infer the normalized source of a pure λ function on Haskell?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

Let a pure λ function be a term with nothing but abstractions and applications. On JavaScript, it is possible to infer the source code of a pure function by applying all abstractions to variadic functions that collect their argument list. That is, this is possible:

```
lambdaSource(function(x){return x(x)}) == "λx.(x x)"
```

See the code for [lambdaSource](https://gist.github.com/MaiaVictor/1f0afbdb0ef173620c95) on this gist. That function became particularly useful for my interests since it allows me to use existing JS engines to normalize untyped lambda calculus expressions much faster than any naive evaluator I could code by myself. Moreover, I know λ-calculus functions can be expressed in Haskell with help of `unsafeCoerce`:

```
(let (#) = unsafeCoerce in (\ f x -> (f # (f # (f # x)))))
```

I do not know how to implement `lambdaSource` in Haskell because of the lack of variadic functions. Is it possible to infer the normalized source of a pure λ function on Haskell, such that:

```
lambdaSource (\ f x -> f # (f # (f # x))) == "λ f x . f (f (f x))"
```

?

Comment: Do you mean untyped lambda calculus?

Comment: The usual approach is rather the other way around: build up a structured representation of the lambda, and only turn it into a (Haskell) lambda at the last second. e.g. you might like to read about [HOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_abstract_syntax), with which you might write `Lambda (\f -> Lambda (\x -> f :# (f :# (f :# x))))` with a suitable data definition.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in Haskell, as functions do not have any runtime representation (in contrast to JS, where they're objects). I guess there's a good reason that there is no `Show` instance for functions either.

Comment: Not every untyped LC term can be assigned a Haskell type. Even if you could write a function like `LambdaTerm a => a -> String`, where `LambdaTerm a` indicates that `a` is a type whose terms are valid terms in the untyped LC, this function would still be partial with respect to the domain of untyped LC terms, ie, there are terms you would not be able to reify because they cannot be written as a haskell function. This is especially unfortunate since the overwhelming majority of untyped LC terms cannot be assigned a Haskell type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you [can](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/TDPE.hs), but you need to provide the spine of the type of your function, so it doesn't work for ULC. See also the whole [lecture notes](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/).

But as **Daniel Wagner** says you can just use HOAS.

There is also another opportunity: here is [something](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/fooling/Jigger.agda) that looks like HOAS, but is FOAS actually, and all you need is suitable normalization by evaluation ([in terms of quote](http://fplab.bitbucket.org/posts/2008-04-13-the-shortest-betanormaliz.html), [in terms of reify & reflect](http://www.diku.dk/OLD/undervisning/2005e/224/papers/DybjerFilinski-NaPE.pdf)). **pigworker** also wrote a Haskell version of the Jigger, but I can't find it.

We can also do this type-safely in type theory: one way is to use [liftable terms](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/Normalization/Liftable.agda) (which requires a postulate), or we can [reify](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/Normalization/PHOAS.agda) lambda terms into their PHOAS representation and then convert [PHOAS to FOAS](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Intensional.html) (which is very complicated).

**EDIT**

Here is some HOAS-related code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, FlexibleInstances #-}

infixl 5 #

data Term a = Pure a | Lam (Term a -> Term a) | App (Term a) (Term a)

(#) :: Term a -> Term a -> Term a
Lam f # x = f x
f     # x = App f x

instance Show (Term String) where
    show = go names where
        names = map (:[]) ['a'..'z'] ++ map (++ ['\'']) names

        go :: [String] -> Term String -> String
        go  ns    (Pure n)  = n
        go (n:ns) (Lam f)   = concat ["\\", n, " -> ", go ns (f (Pure n))]
        go  ns    (App f x) = concat [go ns f, "(", go ns x, ")"]

k :: Term a
k = Lam $ \x -> Lam $ \y -> x

s :: Term a
s = Lam $ \f -> Lam $ \g -> Lam $ \x -> f # x # (g # x)

omega :: Term a
omega = (Lam $ \f -> f # f) # (Lam $ \f -> f # f)

run t = t :: Term String

main = do
    print $ run $ s         -- \a -> \b -> \c -> a(c)(b(c))
    print $ run $ s # k # k -- \a -> a
    -- print $ run $ omega  -- bad idea
```

Also, instead of writing this `Lam`s, `#`s and stuff, you can parse string representations of lambda terms to HOAS — that's not harder than printing HOAS terms.

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm I'm sorry, but I think this doesn't get the normal form of a term. [See here](http://lpaste.net/144108)...

Comment: @Viclib, it's `two = Lam $ \ f -> Lam $ \ x -> f # (f # x)`. Or  if you want to keep your definition, then you need to define a function, that replaces every `App` with `#` in a term.

Comment: Hey, that was obvious. I'm sorry for missing that out. Thank you!